# how to use different shape of UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton

I am having below image for UIButton background image.
But UIbutton shape  by default is round rect.So touch up inside event will work only in round rect area.
So how can i support touchup inside event for below shape (entire area).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Hope this link helps.](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.in/2010/03/irregularly-shaped-uibuttons.html)

To create an irregular shaped button, you need to create custom button and perform hitTest to check if button was pressed or empty space was pressed.

Comment: its been removed.. please suggest another link.. or solution as informatory

Answer (score 1):

You can use UIButtonTypeCustom and give the correct frame.